# Why must a new global variable be created to reference the current class instance in "exec"?

Tags: python, class, global-variables, instance, self

I have a class that contains ~20 methods, and in `def __init__(self, ...):` I have to call many of these methods (~9) but I didn't want to have to call each individual method one by one.

So I took the easy way out and created two list list comprehensions, that use `exec` to call each method:

```
[exec("self.create%s()" % x) for x in "ArticleObjects SeriesObjects ArticleList SearchList".split(" ")]
[exec("self.compile%sPage(self)" % x) for x in "About Screenshots Search Contact Articles".split(" ")]
```

When I ran this code using `python3 filename.py` I got an error, that read:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Through trial and error I found that; in order to get this code to work I had to create a copy of `self` called `instance` and make the new `instance` variable a global variable and then call the method using `ClassName.methodName(instance)` instead of `self.methodName()`:

With the working code being:

```
global instance; instance = self
[exec("ClassNamecreate%s(instance)" % x) for x in "ArticleObjects SeriesObjects ArticleList SearchList".split(" ")]
[exec("ClassName.compile%sPage(instance)" % x) for x in "About Screenshots Search Contact Articles".split(" ")]
```

Why is this? Why is the `self` variable undefined in `exec` despite it being available to the scope that `exec` is being called in?

**Update:** I'm using Python 3.6.7

Comment: [list comprehension in exec with empty locals: NameError](//stackoverflow.com/q/45132645)

Comment: Apart from the unnecessary use of `exec`, it's an anti-pattern to use a list comp purely for side effects. If you don't need the resulting list, then please use a proper loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's lots of good suggestions here for how to avoid the exec statement (which is generally bad), but to answer your question about *why* this happens, it's got more to do with the list comprehension. List comprehensions create a new scope, and when you call exec without a globals or locals argument, it uses the `locals()` function:

> Note: The default locals act as described for function locals() below

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#exec)

Here you can see what the results of the `locals()` function look like from within a list comprehension:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        k = 4
        print(locals())
        exec("print(locals())")
        [print(locals()) for x in range(1)]
        [exec("print(locals())") for x in range(1)]
Sample()
```

output:

```
{'k': 4, 'self': <__main__.Sample object at 0x00000000030295C0>}
{'k': 4, 'self': <__main__.Sample object at 0x00000000030295C0>}
{'x': 0, '.0': <range_iterator object at 0x00000000030019F0>}
{'x': 0, '.0': <range_iterator object at 0x00000000030019F0>}
```

So, `locals()` is the same inside or outside the exec. It's the list comprehension that changes it. Only, when you're outside an exec statement, the interpreter can fall past the locals of the list comprehension and find `self` in the outer scope. No such luck once you call exec.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've replaced the `exec` and now I know what was causing my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using `getattr` is simpler (and usually safer) than `exec`. Try something along these lines:

```
def __init__(self):
    suffixes = ["ArticleObjects", "SeriesObjects", ...]
    for suffix in suffixes:
        method = getattr(self, "create" + suffix)
        method()
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `exec` for this. While it may be the shortest version, it might also confuse both collaborators and code analysis tools. I'd use something like this instead:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        for f in (self.createA, self.createB, self.createC):
            f()

    def createA(self):
        print("A")

    def createB(self):
        print("B")

    def createC(self):
        print("C")
```